# Using textswitcher to add animation not working form xml layout

Tags: android, animation, textview

I have the textSwitcher in xml layout as

```
<TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/feedbackQuestionSwitcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerImg">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/feedbackQuestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/font_semi_bold"
                tools:text="@string/feedback_feeling_better" />
        </TextSwitcher>
```

I am using the animation as below

```
 val inAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
        requireContext(),
        android.R.anim.fade_in
    )
    val outAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
        requireContext(),
        android.R.anim.fade_out
    )
    inAnim.duration = 800
    outAnim.duration = 800


    feedbackIncluded.feedbackQuestionSwitcher.setInAnimation(inAnim)
    feedbackIncluded.feedbackQuestionSwitcher.setOutAnimation(outAnim)
    feedbackIncluded.feedbackQuestion.text = question.question
```

Animation is not appearing when I change the text

Answer (score 0):

When using textswitcher with xml layout we need to have 2 textviews
As factory method recreates a new text view when adding animation

```
<TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/feedbackQuestionSwitcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerImg">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/font_semi_bold"
                tools:text="@string/feedback_feeling_better" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/font_semi_bold"
                tools:text="@string/feedback_feeling_better" />
        </TextSwitcher>
```

Set your animation and set text

```
    feedbackIncluded.feedbackQuestionSwitcher.setInAnimation(
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            requireContext(),
            R.anim.screen_fade_enter
        )
    )
    feedbackIncluded.feedbackQuestionSwitcher.setOutAnimation(
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            requireContext(),
            R.anim.screen_fade_exit
        )
    )
feedbackIncluded.feedbackQuestionSwitcher.setText(question.question)
```